# python3 pexpect how to flush buffer after expect(<string>)

Tags: python-3.x, buffer, pexpect

I am trying to telnet (console using console server) to a Cisco router, run a few show commands, and store the output of them in a variable.

Below simple script works -
Already logged into the router before running script (Not very useful in real world use cases)

```
import telnetlib
import datetime
import getpass
import sys
import re
import time
import pexpect

host1_ip = "192.168.6.131"
host1_port = "32772"
user ="cisco"
password = "cisco123"

tn=pexpect.spawn("telnet " + host1_ip + " " + host1_port, maxread=16384)
tn.sendline("show ip interface brief")
time.sleep(5)
tn.expect("CE1#")
data1=tn.before
print(data1.decode('utf-8'))
```

Output is (data1's contents) :

```
show ip interface brief
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Ethernet0/0                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
Ethernet0/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
Ethernet0/2                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
Ethernet0/3                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
Serial1/0                  unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
Serial1/1                  unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
Serial1/2                  unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
Serial1/3                  unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
```

expect with "CE1#" works, as this is the first occurrence of "CE1#"

However, when I use a more useful script that logs in to the router, configures it, and then gets/stores the output of show commands, it doesnot work.

```
import telnetlib
import datetime
import getpass
import sys
import re
import time
import pexpect

host1_ip = "192.168.6.131"
host1_port = "32772"
user ="cisco"
password = "cisco123"

tn=pexpect.spawn("telnet " + host1_ip + " " + host1_port, maxread=16384)
tn.send("\r")
tn.expect("Username: ")
tn.sendline(user)
tn.expect("Password: ")
tn.sendline(password)

tn.sendline("terminal length 0")
tn.sendline("terminal width 0")
time.sleep(5)
tn.expect("CE1#")
tn.sendeof
tn.sendline("show ip interface brief")
time.sleep(5)
tn.expect("CE1#")
data1=tn.before
print(data1.decode('utf-8'))
tn.sendline("exit")
```

Output is :

```
terminal length 0
```

Expect with "CE1#" after the "show ip interface brief" doesnot work, as "CE1#" is encountered much before.

When I log into the router, "CE1#" is seen.
When I configure "terminal length 0", "terminal width 0", CE1# is seen

```
Username: cisco
Password:
CE1#terminal length 0
CE1#terminal width 0
```

How do I flush out the buffer so that previous encounters of "CE1#" are removed ?
Tried (1) adding 'expect "CE1#" statements before (as ideally child.before should only read output after that last expect'
(2) sending eof (3) sending flush using child.flush etc.
None of them have helped.

Comment: Just as a side note, do you even use telnetlib that you have imported?

Comment: Its just a relic from my previous attempt at using telnetlib. I'll remove it eventually. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No so sure if after 3 years this is usefully but here it goes:

In your case you need to do .sendline('something') .expect('something') in sequence in order to follow properly the buffer.

In your code, maybe the print you expect is in the buffer or in the .after

Anyhow, if you want to **force buffer clear**, use this:

```
 if my_child.before:
           
       my_child.expect(r'.+')
```